# My Jetty server will dead after a long time, why?

Tags: jetty

Recently, I host a website in Amazon EC2, and I use [Jetty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_%28web_server%29) 7.4 as my server.

I test it in my machine and EC2, and it works properly.

But after a few weeks, it suddenly can't be accessed. Checking the log, it just said "/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp" not found. And then the whole site can't be used any more until restarting the Jetty server.

BTW: in my project I used [Spring Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework), [Spring MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Model-view-controller_framework), [Ehcache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehcache), [Shiro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Shiro), [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29), [Google Web Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Web_Toolkit), etc.

Why?

I almost use the default configuration file for Jetty:

**Jetty configuration file:**

```
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Server Thread Pool                                          -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<Set name="ThreadPool">
  <!-- Default queued blocking threadpool -->
  <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
    <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
    <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
    <Set name="detailedDump">false</Set>
  </New>
</Set>

<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Set connectors                                              -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->

<Call name="addConnector">
  <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="jetty.port" default="8080"/></Set>
        <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
        <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
        <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
        <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
    <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
      </New>
  </Arg>
</Call>

<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- Set handler Collection Structure                            -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<Set name="handler">
  <New id="Handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
    <Set name="handlers">
     <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Handler">
       <Item>
         <New id="Contexts" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection"/>
       </Item>
       <Item>
         <New id="DefaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler"/>
       </Item>
     </Array>
    </Set>
  </New>
</Set>

<New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
  <Arg>
    <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
      <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
      <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
      <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
      <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
      <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
    </New>
  </Arg>
</New>

<Call class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log" name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to <Ref id="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
<Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref id="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>

<!-- =========================================================== -->
<!-- extra options                                               -->
<!-- =========================================================== -->
<Set name="stopAtShutdown">true</Set>
<Set name="sendServerVersion">true</Set>
<Set name="sendDateHeader">true</Set>
<Set name="gracefulShutdown">1000</Set>
<Set name="dumpAfterStart">false</Set>
<Set name="dumpBeforeStop">false</Set>
```

### **Error details:**

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6117: File "/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp" not found
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:89)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:169)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.getInputStream(JspUtil.java:910)
    at org.apache.jasper.xmlparser.XMLEncodingDetector.getEncoding(XMLEncodingDetector.java:143)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.determineSyntaxAndEncoding(ParserController.java:376)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:210)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:140)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:435)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:608)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:360)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:486)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:380)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:478)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:284)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1352)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:359)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:275)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:344)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:272)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1323)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:480)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:937)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:183)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:871)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:346)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:589)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:1048)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:529)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run

```
bin/jetty.sh check
```

You may find

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp
```

Change it to some other folder since the OS will delete files in `/tmp` after a period of time.

Comment: yes, i think that's why my application will not work after a fixed time. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 1):

Why is your `index.jsp` in WEB-INF? That folder is made for classes, JAR files, web server files, etc. Your JSP page should just not be there at all.

See *[JSP do not work in Embedded Jetty](http://old.nabble.com/JSP-do-not-work-in-Embedded-Jetty-td17638919.html)*.

Review you `web.xml` and other configuration files.

Comment: Because I use Spring MVC, so i put jsp under WEB-INF as view file. And website work well normally, just after some weeks, it suddenly doesn't work. Is it because of memory issue or others?

Comment: It is necessary to put jsp files in WEB-INF if we want to hide them from direct access.